# Where is the NFC element located in a Moto X?

Tags: hardware, nfc, moto-x, google-wallet

I have a Moto X (2013 version) -- and use Google Wallet's tap-to-pay at merchants that support it.  With certain readers, I end up moving the phone around over the reader until it works; knowing where the element is might make it easier to line it up correctly on the first try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check [iFixit Moto X Teardown](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Motorola+Moto+X+Teardown/16867). Looks like it takes up most of the center of the back.